# linkedin language code change

Tags: javascript, django, linkedin-api

I am a beginner in programming and I have been able to add the linkedin share button to a test webpage.

I now want to change the language of the linkedin share button, so that it will change language when the user changes their language on the test web page.

Linkedin users a five character langauge code `(ru_RU, en_US, ko_KR, etc)`. My test webpage uses a two character language code `(ru, en, ko)`, so I have to write a `js` function to return the five character language code.

I am using django 1.4 and the `"{{ user.get_profile.language_preference }}"` returns the two character language code.

Here is what I attempted to "convert" the language code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function language_code_extended(){
            var language_code_value = "{{ user.get_profile.language_preference }}";
            if ( language_code_value == ru ) { 
                return "ru_RU"
            }
            else if ( language_code_value == "fr" ) { 
                return "fr_FR"
            }
            else if ( language_code_value == "ko" ) {  
                return "ko_KR"
            }
            else {
                return "en_US"
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Here is my linkedin share button code:

```
    <!-- LinkedIn Like Button code -->
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
        //lang: ru_RU
        lang: language_code_extended()
    </script>
```

This does not work. Can someone point out what I have done wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using a different method - not JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to quote the strings you're comparing to, for example:

```
language_code_value == ru
```

should be

```
language_code_value == "ru"
```

otherwise the comparison will be looking for a variable named `ru` to compare to.

There are a few additional issues to address in making this conversion:

- Having an `if` condition test for every language you'll want to deal with is quickly going to become unwieldy and error prone.
- This mapping is taking a language code `ru` and mapping to a code representing and language *and* a country `ru_RU`. This involves making an assumption that somebody speaking a certain language is in a certain country, which is not generally correct. Many languages are spoken in multiple countries with different conventions in each.

It might be worth your while to dig a little deeper to find a better way of doing this. This will likely result in less effort and a more correct solution.

I'm sorry, I don't know Django so I can't point you in the right direction, but you might want to explore whether it, or a third party package, can return you the correct IETF language tag directly.

**Edit**

You're also going to have problems with:

```
var language_code_value = "{{ user.get_profile.language_preference }}";
```

`language_code_value` is going to have the literal string value `{{ user.get_profile.language_preference }}` which is never going to compare equal to the two digit language codes you want to compare it to.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the inverted commas were not around the js variables. This was a typo. I have edited this and it does not appear to make a difference.

Comment: The language code ru_RU is used by LinkedIn and Facebook, so I have to change the langauage code to their format.

Comment: Yes, you have to convert to the IETF language tag format they expect, but I'm just drawing your attention to the fact that that tag includes some extra information that you're guessing at in your current implementation.

Comment: I've edited my answer to point out another potential issue. If this doesn't help, could you detail what you expect to happen and what's actually happening?

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I was thinkg that the code: "var language_code_value = "{{ user.get_profile.language_preference }}";" would set the variable "language_code_value" to ko and then the js would match the "else if ( language_code_value == "ko" ) { return "ko_KR"} assigning the value of ko to lang: language_code_extended()

Comment: I'm not familiar with the context, but would assume you're after something more like: var language_code_value = user.get_profile.language_preference;